# Value Error: '10.0.0.150' is an Invalid IP version!' using netaddr library

Tags: python

I'm using the CSV module, as well as netaddr. When I print a single row of IPs, while casting them as an IP and then as an int, it prints fine. When I print a second row with the first row, I then get an error saying "Value Error: '10.0.0.150' is an Invalid IP version!'.

```
import csv
from netaddr import *
with open('DHCPranges.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            print(int(IPAddress(row['start_address*'], row['end_address*'])))
```

my csv file is as follows:

```
[Network]      [start_address*] [end_address*]
Chris's Network 10.0.0.1         10.0.0.150
John's Network  10.0.0.152       10.0.0.254
```

it works when I do just this:

```
import csv
from netaddr import *
with open('DHCPranges.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
      for row in reader:
          print(int(IPAddress(row['start_address*'])))
```

Comment: What is the source of the `IPAddress` class?

Comment: netaddr module (https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(int(IPAddress(row['start_address*'], row['end_address*'])))
```

You're passing both columns to the `IPAddress` constructor. But the constructor takes only one IP at a time. The second argument is for IP version.  So when you construct the `IPAddress` object it tries to parse the end address as the version. Which causes the issue.

You should construct two separate `IPAddress` objects and convert them to integer like this:

```
print(int(IPAddress(row['start_address*'])), int(IPAddress(row['end_address*'])))
```

Your second example works perfectly because then you're passing just one, exactly what the constructor expects.

Answer (score 0):

Read your code carefully.  This is why simpler and shorter expressions are preferred over longer ones: it is easier to write (and read) correctly.

Try this:

```
raw_start_addr = row['start_address*']
start_addr = IPAddress(raw_start_addr)
packed_start_addr = int(start_addr)

raw_end_addr = row['end_address*']
end_addr = IPAddress(raw_end_addr)
packed_end_addr = int(end_addr)

print(packed_start_addr, packed_end_addr)
```

Then [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) it:

```
def convert(raw_addr):
    addr = IPAddress(raw_addr)
    packed_addr = int(addr)
    return pack_addr

packed_start_addr = convert( row['start_address*'] )
packed_end_addr = convert( row['end_address*'] )
print(packed_start_addr, packed_end_addr)
```

Your problem is that you did not print two addresses.  You still passed only one value to `print()`, except that due to the exception that was raised that call never happened.  You passed two arguments to the `IPAddress` constructor.  That has a very different meaning!

---

*Updated*: the question was clarified, in a comment, that the IPAddress class is from the [`netaddr`](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/) library.

The documentation for the [`IPAddress` class' constructor](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/api.html#netaddr.IPAddress) shows that the second argument is the version of the IP protocol that defines the address format.  The two (current) versions are 4 and 6.  Thus a string containing the characters `10.0.0.150` is not a valid version of the IP protocol and thus is not valid as a second argument to `IPAddress()`.  This can also be seen in the [tutorial you referenced in your comment where it shows IPv6 support](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html#ipv6-support).

Comment: I see, what I wanted was to have two separate IPAddress objects, thank you.

Comment: All the refactoring talk is kind of superfluous, given the error nor is it an obvious improvement over such a short expression.

Comment: @pvg The error was the mix of punctuation and noise in the OP's statement: he thought he was simply printing two values when that was not the case.  That is why I advised separating those steps from the call to print() so it would become clear.  Then I revised the question summary to reflect the actual error since it had nothing to do with CSV or printing.